# instagram API python библиотека

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

Есть ли какая-нибудь python библиотека для управления instagram аккаунтом?
Порыл интернет, не разобрался.
Пробовал через selenium, но это очень не удобно.
Хотелось бы найти библиотеки похожие на библиотеки для Telegram Api

Comment: У инстаграм нет открытого API, в отличие от того же Telegram, поэтому так же удобно в любом случае не получится.

Comment: Есть другие способы? И какие самые удобные?